# problem in uninstall chrome. i got error so that i could open ubuntu software center too

Tags: sudo

sir i installed chrome by typing following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:a-v-shkop/chromium-dev
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

then i got big error i can't uninstall chrome. i got one error when i open ubuntu software center and it is not at all opening and it is saying ubuntu experience internal error.the following is the type of error is showing in pop up menu.

```
Could not initialize the package information

An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.

Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:

'E:Type 'ain' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/a-v-shkop-chromium-precise.list'
```

i tried to uninstall chrome using purge command in termaial...nothing is working. in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable 
[sudo] password for dhinesh: 
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... 
Done E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

The PPA you added is not intended for users, only for developers.
You don't need the PPA to install chromium-browser, it is in the standard repository.

You must remove the PPA. Normally this is done through synaptic packet manager but I assume you don't have that installed and you can't install anything at the moment.

in that case you can remove it manually like this:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/a-v-shkop-chromium-dev-precise.list
```

then clean the packet cache and run the update again:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

then you might like to have the normal chromium-browser from the standard repository:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium browser
```

If you encounter any errors, please add them to your question